# How do I provision a Dockerfile from Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, docker

How can I start the provisioning of Docker via an external `Dockerfile`? My `Vagrantfile` looks like this at the moment:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.define :server_infrastructure do |t|
  end

  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.pull_images "ubuntu"
    #how does the below work?
    #d.build "new-container-name" "local-docker-file-name"
  end
end
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[An option for the Docker provisioner to build images](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/2615) was added in [v1.6.0](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160-unreleased). Download the latest version from [the Vagrant website](http://www.vagrantup.com/).

Once you've done that, put a `Dockerfile` next to your `Vagrantfile`. Add this to your `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.build_image "/vagrant", args: "-t my-name/my-new-image"
  d.run "my-name/my-new-image"
end
```

Now your Docker image will be built and run with `vagrant up`.

Comment: Executing this Vagranfile returns: There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

docker provider:
* One of "build_dir" or "image" must be set

Comment: This is for the Docker provisioner, for bringing up Docker images as part of bringing up a VM. It is not for the Docker provider, which brings up Docker images natively on Linux or in a minimal VM on OS X. See: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3721#issuecomment-42600273

Answer (score 3):

one workaround is through shell provisioning:

```rb
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker build -t username/image /vagrant; docker run -d username/image"
```

Answer (score 1):

For docker to build an image from a `dockerfile`, `dockerfile` in question must be presented in the guest machine and the way to ensure this is to use shared folder feature of vagrant.

By default vagrant mounts your project root folder to the new vm under the name `/vagrant`. But in your case i suggest you share a different folder and put your dockerfiles there. Also by sharing a different folder you can make sure that your dockerfiles are seen read-only by the guest machine.

Now suppose you create a new folder in your projects root directory named "docker" and put your dockerfiles in it. Now if you mount this folder to your guest machine and point docker to use that file you are all set. if you add these lines to your vagrant file it will work as expected.

```rb
    config.vm.synced_folder "docker/", "/docker_builds", create: true, mount_options: ["ro"]
    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
      d.build_image "/docker_builds", args: "-t my-name/my-new-image"
      d.run "my-name/my-new-image"
    end`
```