# Build a docker image from vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant

I would like to build a Docker image from Vagrant container.
The Vagrant environment is functioning without any problems.

I created a Dockerfile:

```
touch Dockerfile
```

I created myapp directory within Vagrant machine directory (I am not sure if I should do this or not):

```
mkdir myapp
```

I added these lines to Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |docker|
    docker.build_image "/vagrant/myapp"
  end
```

I had this error:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

docker build  /vagrant/myapp

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
time="2015-06-01T12:34:44Z" level=fatal msg="Cannot locate Dockerfile: Dockerfile"
```

**What do you think I am missing ?**

## Update

This is the application file tree:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── myapp/
└── Vagrantfile
```

Comment: Is the Dockerfile alongside the Vagrantfile and you are in the same directory yourself ?

Comment: Yes, the Dockerfile is in the same tree level as Vagrantfile. I am inside the directory since `vagrant up` works for me.

Comment: can you do an ls -l and add to your output in the question maybe

Comment: Your command `docker build  /vagrant/myapp` is strange, you should either 1) `cd where_is_my_Dockerfile` and then `docker build .` or `docker build -t mytag .` 2) or, if you have at least docker 1.5  `docker build --file="/abc/def/"`

Comment: I was following this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167531/how-do-i-provision-a-dockerfile-from-vagrant